# How can I distinguish users from robots to use server side rendering with all bots?

Tags: web-crawlers, user-agent, render

How can I reliably distinguish users from robots?

We have an ecommerce shop that goes through some heavy traffic peaks at some times. We would like to move some/all of the load during these peaks to client side rendering (CSR), while also allowing robots to continue crawling our site with server side rendering (SSR) enabled only for them.

*PS: The content is exactly the same for SSR and CSR.*

*This is basically our situation exactly: [Operationalizing Node.js for Server Side Rendering - Airbnb Engineering & Data Science - Medium](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/operationalizing-node-js-for-server-side-rendering-c5ba718acfc9)*